# ./gradle genSources exception with Java version

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I have an exception when I write `./gradlew genSource` in terminal.

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fabric-example-mod-1.19\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '0.12-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > You are using an outdated version of Java (8). Java 17 or higher is required.
     The JAVA_HOME environment variable is currently set to (C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.332.9-hotspot\).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I saw my version of Java is old, but when I go to *File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle* and change the Gradle JVM to ProjectSDK and try again, nothing changes.

[image: this setting]

Java 17 was downloaded and my Gradle was successfully build. Version of fabric for Minecraft is 1.19.

Comment: Can you try running `./gradlew -v`?

Comment: ```------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-02-08 09:58:38 UTC
Revision:     f0d9291c04b90b59445041eaa75b2ee744162586

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_332 (Temurin 25.332-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: Update `JAVA_HOME` to point to JDK 17 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html